# Calculate rows in file from object size is not working

Tags: serialization, visual-c++, mfc

Context: MFC programming

I am using `CArchive` and `CFile` to write records to a file.
The file size is smaller than the corresponding object sizes.
I.e.: The object size is 48 and the file size 44
I hoped I could do: `FileSize`/`Object` size in order to determine
the number of rows. This does not work. Also: I am not only writing
one record, but multiple record with the same problem into a file.

```
CFile file;
BOOL bret = file.Open("aFile.bin", CFile::modeCreate|CFile::modeWrite);
//if (!bRet) return;
CFileStatus status;
file.GetStatus(status);
ULONGLONG size = status.m_size;// file size corresponds to dir command file size
//The file size is smaller than the object size.
// Here is the Object code
CArchive(&file, CFile::store);
CData t;
t.ID = "Hello World!";
t.Serialize(ar); // This writes the data to the Cfile declared above
ar.Close();
file.Close();
}

class CData {
public:
CData() = default;
~CData() = default;
CString ID;
void Serialize(CArchive& ar) {
if (ar.IsStoring() ar << ID;
else ar >> ID;
}
DECLARE_SERIAL(CData);
};
...
sizeof(CData); // i.e. == 48
// sizeof File is: 132 (3 records at 44 bytes)
//...
```

How can I find out how many records are in my file without using a file header?

Comment: You can't. You either have to explicitly write out the object count, or use some sort of sentinel that acts as an end-of-sequence marker. Though, really, the most straight forward way is to write an explicit count to the file. It's what the default MFC classes do as well (e.g. `CString`). Why don't you want a header?

Comment: Also, don't fool yourself into thinking that `CArchive`s were just binary data. The file format is a lot more involved and includes type information as well.

Comment: I hoped that my calculation would be sufficient. Additionally I added a second class derived from CObject implenting the  Serialize function.i added a counter for the number of rows and it seems to work using a single archive and two classes performing serialization. For some reason storing the read data in to a vector of LVITEM array seems to have impact on data integrity. Keep things simple was my reason to avoid a header record. Maybe to not introducing an entirely new structure to archive, but a variant (inion) for the header record would resolve  my problem.

Comment: [TN002: Persistent Object Data Format](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn002-persistent-object-data-format) describes the internals of the file format. If you need a simple binary file format, don't use `CArchive`. Either way, though, as soon as your data contains variable-sized values (like character strings), you're going to have to find a way for the deserializer to discover the actual payload size. Writing out a size prefix is the simplest, most flexible and robust solution. A note on `vector`: Unlike the MFC containers, a `vector` doesn't know how to (de)serialize itself.

Comment: I believe I have everything I need. Thank you for link and comments.